# Account Section deploy to Production

Tags: visualforce, page-layout

I have created one secetion on the Account Object.Section name is "Account Order Info",In that secetion I have attached to one VF page in sandbox.Now my question is how to deploy the my section to Production?
I know how to deploy the VF page to Production.
Suppose I deploy VF page to Production it show's section on the Account?
Otherwise we will create new section then attached to my VF page?in the Production.

Thanks & Best Regards,
Ramesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is a bit ambiguously worded but I gather that you want to push your VF page changes to production. There are multiple ways to do so. One of easiest ones is to create a change set and follow these steps

Configure the deployment connection on both your production and sandbox org.

```
Setup> App Setup > Deploy > Deployment connections
```

Once that is done you can make and outbound change set on your sandbox

```
Setup> App Setup > Deploy > Outbound Change Sets
```

Once you've added your VF pages and apex class(es) click the add/View dependencies button and you'll see that it will list metadata such as the custom object you're using. Once you upload your change set a target organisation you'll be able to validate and deploy it there.

Comment: I am agree to answer but I created one section on Account object,This section attached VF page,How to deploy the my Account page layout

Comment: Include your page layout in the Change Set. Refer this link for the full list of components that can be deployed via a Change Set - http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=changesets_about_components.htm&language=en_US

Comment: If my answer helped resolve your issue, please mark as it Accepted for everybody's benefit. Thanks!

Comment: +1 Gaurav. While deploying when u click on View dependencies it will display the list which uses the vf like page layout ,Account object name ...there select all and proceed.